# Installing meld on OS X

Tags: meld

After I got MacPorts installed and did a 'sudo port -v selfupdate', I try to install meld.

The installation just starts to Fetching all kinds of stuff
gnome-comoon
perl5.8
perl5
pkgconfig
.....
this goes on and on.

Is that normal?

Answer (score 19):

You may want to install it via HomeBrew (already mentioned before):

```
brew install homebrew/gui/meld
```

Though you may face stability issues (as I did). So I'd rather recommend to use "Meld for OSX":

- Go to https://yousseb.github.io/meld/
- Download DMG file you prefer (e.g. "Download latest DMG" https://github.com/yousseb/meld/releases/download/osx-6/meldmerge.dmg)
- Install it to your Applications folder

We are basically done, but it is not accessible via command line.

Solution:

- Write a small wrapper to run from Terminal:

  ```
  echo -e '#!/bin/sh
  params="$@"
  open -W -a Meld --args $params' | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/meld
  sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/meld
  ```
- Try (**you must use absolute paths though**):

  ```
  meld /home/a.txt /home/b.txt
  ```

  Or just run Meld from menu.

Comment: See the answer from @Headroom for the current method. This is no longer valid

Comment: The command line accessibility info is useful if not essential.  Here's a bash alias that works for me with this OSX Meld:  function meld () { open -a /Applications/Meld.app/ --args "$@";}

Answer (score 9):

[meld](http://meldmerge.org/) is [now available](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/meld.rb) in [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/). The formula [can be found here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/meld.rb).

See this [answer by cmedeiros on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/422588/218141) for more information on installing and getting it to work.  This is much easier than using MacPorts.

Comment: I get a 404 when I click on the 'can be found here' link

Comment: The formula was moved again, try this `brew install caskroom/cask/meld`

Comment: Formula update: `brew tap homebrew/cask` , then install with `brew cask install meld`

Answer (score 9):

Current command with updated formula to install meld with homebrew is:

```
brew install caskroom/cask/meld
```

Comment: This is the current method as the accepted answer is no longer valid

Comment: Formula update: `brew tap homebrew/cask` , then install with `brew cask install meld`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is normal to pull in dependencies but it shouldn't take too long. For comparison, installing Meld with Homebrew took about 15 minutes for me.

For reference, my installation of Meld on OS X Mavericks:

- Install Xcode from the app store
- Install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) from package (Meld will complain if you don't have it)
- command line: 'brew install meld'

If you are prompted to install the Xcode command line tools at some point, do so.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't include how to install brew which can be found [here](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-homebrew-os-x-yosemite-10-10-package-manager-unix-apps/). Also the final brew command was: `brew install homebrew/x11/meld`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the **is** very *normal* with MacPorts, and is the reason that people many have switched to homebrew http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

However, I found this post because homebrew doesn't include Meld. Sigh.

Comment: Same situation here. Trying to install Meld and macports wants to *start* by compiling GCC. <sigh> There are about 10 other dependencies, too, so I'll be ready to use meld in about 12 hours :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider downloading macOS meld version dmg https://github.com/yousseb/meld/releases/

Answer (score 0):

Brew now works `brew install --cask meld`.
See https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/meld#default

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE Jul-23-2020**

Just do :

brew install homebrew/gui/meld

Answer (score -1):

using the updated brew link: brew install caskroom/cask/meld

even after this its not working when I install backup and restore tool by google. I guess its messing up with the python version.